# using open cloud api without composer

Tags: php, php-opencloud

I am trying to use the rackspace php SDK to update to the new API since the old one has been deprecated for a while. I am trying to use the SDK without using composer since we cannot install composer on the production server. I was wondering if anyone has any pointers to this or if anyone has successfully done so. At this point the only solution I have found is to manually require the files necessary to the specific files but this will take forever.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I may be saying something stupid since I dont know exsactly how composer work but, Could you install composer on an development server install all the sdk then only copy those files ?

Comment: No that I know of. Composer would have to be installed on the production server for it to work

Comment: I never actually used composer but, I was under the impression it is actually only an little php software that is actually getting all the dependency files for you, and that once all file are downloaded composer is not needed any more.  I may be wrong tho, But i would definitely give try.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could try what Nicolas is suggesting in the comment. So something like this:

1. On your dev machine, install Composer and use it to require the SDK in your project like so:

   ```
   devmachine $ cd /path/to/your/project
   devmachine $ composer require rackspace/php-opencloud 1.9.*
   ...
   devmachine $ cd ..
   devmachine $ tar cvzf project.tgz project/
   ```
2. Upload `project.tgz` from your dev machine to your production environment and untar it in the appropriate place.
3. Everything should just work in the production environment, even without Composer itself being installed in that environment.